# Codeigniter : Passing ajax based data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am fetching cities data based on the `onchange()` event against selected country. 
I have to populate cities data based on country selected.

```
class ajax extends CI_Controller {
    public function getcities(){
        if($this->input->post('countryId')){
            $countryId= $this->input->post('countryId');
        }
        foreach ($this->user_model->getselectedcity($this->input->post('countryId')) as $key => $value) {
             $cities[] = $value->city; 
        }
        echo json_encode($cities);
    }
 }
```

In my view I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#changecountry').change(function(){
            //alert($(this).val());
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/ajax/getcities",
                data:{countryId:$(this).val()}, 
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

These are my dropdowns:

```
<?php 
if($value['type']=='countryname'){
    if(isset($value['countryname'])){
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo form_dropdown('countryname', $value['options'],'','class="form-control" id="changecountry"');
        echo '</div>'; 
    }
} 
if($value['type']=='cityname'){
    if(isset($value['cityname'])){
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo form_dropdown('cityname',$value['options'],'','class="form-control"');
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

In the success function I'm getting json data, I'm not sure how to pass this to the dropdown:

```
["Dubai","Sharjah","Abu Dhabi","Ajman","Ras al-Khaimah","Umm al-Quwain"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append Ajax response with your City dropdown by using ID attribute like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#changecountry').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/ajax/getcities",
                data:{countryId:$(this).val()}, 
                success: function(response){
                    $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                        $("#selectID").append("<option value='"+value+"'>" + value + "</option>");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Your Drop Down (add ID attribute here):**

```
<?php
if($value['type']=='cityname'){
    if(isset($value['cityname'])){
        echo '<div class="form-group">';
        echo form_dropdown('cityname',$value['options'],'','class="form-control" id="selectID"');
        echo '</div>';
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Controller**

```
foreach ($this->user_model->getselectedcity($this->input->post('countryId')) as $option) {
     $cities[] = '<option value="'.$option["city"].'">'.$option["city"].'</option>';
}
```

**In AJAX**

```
success: function(html)
{
    $("#state").html(html);
}
```

**In HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
    <option selected="selected">--Select State--</option>
</select>
```